# Install bitcoin core on debian jessie error

Tags: bitcoin-core, linux, op-return

I have to install bitcoin core to use op_return library. 
But I have difficulties to install correctly bitcoin core.

First I run the command `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin`

Second I enter this command: `apt-get update`

But I have error :

```
 Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages                
 Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages                                                                     
 Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages                                               
 Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages                                               
 Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages                                               
404  Not Found

 W: Failed to fetch http:/ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

So when I want to do this : `apt-get install bitcoin-qt`
I have : `E: Unable to locate package bitcoin-qt`

What can I do?

Comment: I'm getting this same message, anyone with an answer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The repository is for ubuntu and you're on debian.
So it doesn't have packages for jessie.
Use this instead: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md
Hope this helps! :)